# This while loop does its proper function, but required for something else?

Tags: c++

I am making a Hotel Reservation program in C++. When the user wants to open a guest's info file, they have to input the first name and surname of the guest. If there isn't a data file with that name in it, it tells the user that the file doesn't exist. Then asks again for the file name, and the user inputs the real file name.

The problem is that if someone inputs a file name that they know is real, it will say that the file doesn't exist. But if they re-enter the file name when prompted, it loads the file.

By the way, this loop is required for the file to open. That's the main thing I'm stumped about. I tried messing around with it to see if I really needed it, and I do apparently. And I also need the first `file_ptr.open(filename,ios::in);` , along with the second. I also don't understand why I need both.

here is the specific code for that while loop:

```
cout << "Open Member File";
system ("cls");
char filename [100];
ifstream file_ptr;
cout << "\n\t\t\t\tSaved Members:\n\n";
system ("dir/b *.");
cout << "\n\nPlease type the name of the member you\n";
cout << "     wish to open as it appears above OR\n";
cout << "     type z (Lower case) to return to main menu: ";
cin.ignore();
gets (filename);

if (filename[0]  != 'z')
{

    //cout<< "\nPlease enter 6 digit Registration Access Code: ";
    //cin>>RAC;

    //if (RAC == (file_ptr, membershipNumber))
    //{
           file_ptr.open(filename,ios::in);

           // char in_char;
           while(!file_ptr)
           {
              cout << "Member does not exist\n";
              gets (filename);
              file_ptr.open(filename,ios::in);

           }
```

I don't understand why the while loop would be required to open the file if the user gave a legit file name. But it always says the file doesn't exist, then opens file on second try.

**this is the output:**

Saved Members:

Hunter Grad

Please type the name of the member you wish to open as it appears above OR
type z (Lower case) to return to main menu:     Hunter Grad

Member does not exist

**The second time I input the same file name, it takes me to the file**

I don't understand why though? I was hoping someone would know. thanks

Comment: What is `cin.ignore();` doing there? Also, `file_ptr` is not a pointer, so that name is... somewhat confusing.

Comment: ignoring stuff. lol. that might be part of the problem.

Comment: I removed it and it works now. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/

You tell the input stream to ignore one character, so the filename is not what you typed.  If they typed "John" then you try to open the file "ohn".

If you had looked at the variable in a debugger or just checked your output, it would have been obvious. The debugger will be FAR more effective at solving most problems than stackoverflow. You want to come here when you really get stuck.

The second time they type in "John" you look for a file named "John", since there is no ignore in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Erase the cin.ignore() and try again.See here about ignore -> http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/